# No recargar una pagina web. javascript

Tags: php, javascript

lo que quiero es que el cliente no recargue una pagina web o si recarga me mejor cerrar la ventana.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "seguro que desea salir."; }
```

Esto no me funciona porque recarga.

Comment: No puede  ni debería evitar que el usuario  actualice.

Comment: ambas.....=)...

Comment: por que.......?

Comment: No debería modificar las características del navegador además algunos navegadores no permiten esto. ¿Qué desea lograr ? quizá podría plantear otra solución